# Wordpress 301 redirect issue with the base category

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect, http-redirect

What is the proper way of 301 redirecting in the following scenario?

http://example.com/physician needs to be redirected to http://example.com/our-physicians

http://example.com/physician/sample-doctor needs to function as it is

I have tried the following redirect, but it breaks the functinality of the second criteria:

```
Redirect 301 /physician http://example.com/our-physicians/
```

This is a WordPress website by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin a few times before and been pretty pleased with it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: http://example.com/physician page is a taxonomy archive page, it's not a regular page where I can use a plugin for.